# Extract Only Whole Word That Has The First Letter Capitalized

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file need to be analyzed here,  what I am interested is only the whole word with the first letter capitalized,

For example: test string: `Everyday HOLDS the poSSibility Of A Miracle`

I want to capture:  `Everyday Of A Miracle`

I am currently trying to build my regular expression in Python, strangely, my regex only can capture the first whole word that is captalized.

Test String: `Everyday HOLDS the poSSibility Of A Miracle`

My regex:   `^([A-Z])?([a-z])+`

Capture:    `Everyday`

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I would split the text on space and filter each word with the regex. Also, shouldn't the regex demand the first letter to be `[A-Z]`? Isn't `?` after a capture group used for optionals?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of anchoring the regex at the beginning of the string, utilize boundary checking:

```
import re
s = 'Everyday HOLDS the poSSibility Of A Miracle'
new_s = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]+|\b[A-Z]\b', s))
```

Output:

```
'Everyday Of A Miracle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex (only if words are delimited by whitespaces):

```
>>> s='Everyday HOLDS the poSSibility Of A Miracle'
>>> [x for x in s.split() if x.title()==x]
['Everyday', 'Of', 'A', 'Miracle']
```

Note that you can also use re.split to split on any non-letter characters.