# how to implement regular expression to get exact names in a string

Tags: python, regex-lookarounds

How to extract exact name by a string using re library e.g

Code:

```
import re
Str1 = "Saad is 21 years old  bbb b and WhatsApp Shoib is 23 years old Sohail is 24.  I Years old Nimra is 18 years old HellonKaler  is 112 years old and Yusra is 20 years old Mariyam is 19 years old Behzad is 55 years old"
Name = re.findall(r"[A-Z][A-Z]?[a-z]*", Str1)
Age = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}", Str1)
for name in Name:
    print(name)
for age in Age:
     print(age)
```

output:

```
Saad
Whats
App
Shoib
Sohail
I
Years
Nimra
Hellon
Kaler
Yusra
Mariyam
Behzad
21
23
24
18
112
20
19
55
```

Question:

We are interested to extract exact `WhatsApp` not separately from this string.

Comment: But you'd still want to get `Hellon` and `Kaler` as separate matches? Is `WhatsApp` a fixed exception? Or, do you mean you would like to match as a single word all words ending with `App`? Try `[A-Z][A-Z]?[a-z]*(?:App)?`

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422093/regex-finding-capital-words-in-string

Comment: I saw this solution somewhere:
"\b[A-Z][A-Z?[a-z]*\b"

I really don't know why [A-Z?[a-z] is working like that!

Comment: I do not know how [Extract Only Whole Word That Has The First Letter Capitalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203857/extract-only-whole-word-that-has-the-first-letter-capitalized) can be used to close this current question, [that solution does not help here](https://regex101.com/r/uG1LBH/1). Saad Alam, you must clarify the rules for extracting in the question if you need an answer. Please update it and let know via a comment.

Comment: Any feedback? Or shall we remove the "question"?